# How to use or add android library(aar) file in kivy project?

Tags: kivy

I have android library file. I am using this in some android apps developement.
But now I want to use this library in kivy framework. Can we directly use this aar file in kivy project?
Is this possible in kivy?
I am new to kivy framework.

Comment: post what you have done so far

Comment: @AnanthaRajuC The question does not require that some code be provided since he is not pointing out that something is failing but is asking if a .aar with kivy can be used.

Comment: Is anyone has idea on this?

Comment: It seems that the `aar` format is just `zip`, so you could probably unzip the file. Note that there may be `jni` files in it which will be in native code.